# Ruby on Rails: alternative to nested partials (which are too slow)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need my Rails application to generate huge table (about 5-7 columns, and about 2000-3000 rows), it is for internal company usage so we don't care about traffic and so on.

The structure of objects being displayed should be quite flexible: when some column gets added/changed/removed, it is changed in just one place (apart from modifying db schema), and all the views (index, show, edit form) get updated automatically.

I had totally no experience in Rails before. I took partials as a way to reuse code (which is good thing), and so, I've seen nothing bad in using nested sub-sub-sub-partials. Say, I have several models, `index` view of each of them `render`s generic partial `gen_index`, and for each cell of the table there is special partial `gen_field_view`.

The same partial `gen_field_view` is rendered from the `show` views, so, I'd really like to have it as a partial.

If I have even just 600 rows and 5 columns, this partial gets rendered 3000 times. This was a huge surprise for me that it is so hard for Rails: it currently takes about 7 seconds to generate the page. If I remove `gen_field_view` partial and include it directly into `gen_index` partial, it takes about 3 seconds: more than twice faster (which is quite slow anyway, but this is different story).

It seems, we should avoid nested partials for such cases, but then, **what else should we use to reuse views code?**

We probably can return html code from some method in the model, but it actually kills the idea of Rails, and, after all, it's not convenient.

Comment: If you're running in development, then check how fast things are in production - in development rails does a lot more checking of whether the partials have changed on disk

Comment: @FrederickCheung you're right, in production it works about 2-3 times faster. But even then, if I remove partial and include it directly, the difference is about 2 times once more. I'm very disappointed by that slowness of partials in Rails.

Answer (score 1):

What about using a caching strategy ? You can use [rail's fragment cashing feature](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#fragment-caching):

```
<% Product.all.each do |p| %>
  <% cache(p) do %>
    <%= render partial: 'some_partial', locals: {product: p} %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Theres a gem that does this:
http://ninjasandrobots.com/rails-faster-partial-rendering-and-caching

Comment: Why use a gem to do this since it was integrated in rails 4 (see https://github.com/rails/cache_digests)? Plus this gem does not look maintained anymore (https://github.com/n8/multi_fetch_fragments)

Comment: @DimitriJorge for some reason, with `cache` you suggested it even takes longer than without it: Without cache: `Completed 200 OK in 7666ms (Views: 7458.6ms | ActiveRecord: 202.6ms)`, With cache: `Completed 200 OK in 8135ms (Views: 7917.0ms | ActiveRecord: 212.3ms)`

Comment: The first render should take longer yes, but the followings should in theory be much faster

Comment: Strangely enough, the following takes `7697ms`, which is still a bit slower than without caching at all.

Comment: The reason the following requests still takes a long time is, that rails digests all partials to generate a cache key which depends on the content. It does this again and again. It takes a couple of ms for each partial. Summing up to a big total in your case.

Comment: You need to cache whole `each` block to make it sence

Answer (score 0):

Some of the things you can try are

- [Caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#fragment-caching) the main partial result which will then be reused while the record isn't updated
- Render records as json on the page and render a template of the table row and then use javascript to render the actual table

  ```
  <div id="data" data-records="<%= @products.to_json %>"></div>

  <script>
  jQuery.each(jQuery("#data").data("records"), function(record) {
    jQuery("<li>").text(record.title).appendTo("#my-table")
  })
  </script>
  ```
- Use pagination with a gem like [will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate) and then reduce the amount of records showing on the page at the same time
- Use a presentation object that renders the html as string

  ```
  class ModelPresentation
    def initialize(model)
      @model = model
    end

    def render
      [title, rate].join
    end

    def title
      "<h3>@model.title</h3>"
    end

    def rates
      "<span>Rate #{@model.score}</span>"
    end
  end
  ```